# multiple types of info display from mysql db

Tags: mysql, php

I have received great help and direction here recently so I'm back!  The project is gathering a list of available care facilities and have the user be able to search the dB.  So, i have the information about each one being displayed according to the user entering CITY and SPECIALTY information --- all good --- but now I want to include DAYS OPEN and INSURANCE ACCEPTED in the displayed information.  I have each entered into the dB in separate rows - i.e. WEDNESDAY = 1 if open, 0 if closed.

I am using the following to display the information that matches the user search criteria, and now want to include (i.e.) DAYS OPEN.

```
    <?php

        $city = $_GET['city'];
        $specialty = $_GET['specialty'];

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT name, agency, address, city, email, phone FROM counselors WHERE city ='$city' AND specialty LIKE '%$specialty%';");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
            echo $row['name'] . "<br>" . $row['agency'] . "<br>" . $row['address'] . "<br>" . $row['city'] . "<br>" . $row['email'] . "<br>" . $row['phone'];
            echo "<br><br><br>";
    }
        mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

So if the info in the dB shows "1" for Wednesday, my webpage displays 'open on "WEDNESDAY" etc.  My dB is constructed with each day of the week as it's own row and the entry is "1" if open and "0" if closed.

Comment: If a facility is open on Wednesdays, how do you store what happens on the 1th January 2020, which happens to be a Wednesday?    Also, can you share with us how you created the table that holds this info [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language)

Comment: Not worried about particular days, just Mon-Sun open or closed.  Help me understand what it means to share how the table was created.  I use XAMPP on my Win 10 pc.  I used the SQL tab in phpMyAdmin and entered information to create the table.  I then created an HTML form and entered data from there to test and make sure it all worked.  Do you need a screen shot of the dB?

Comment: in a query tab (it's been a while since I used phpMyAdmin), type `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename`, and replace tablename with the name of your table.

Comment: 127.0.0.1/cmh/counselors/  http://localhost/phpmyadmin/tbl_sql.php?db=cmh&table=counselors
Your SQL query has been executed successfully.

SHOW CREATE TABLE cmh.counselors



counselors CREATE TABLE `counselors` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned... 
  is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: You have 7 rows per establishment, one per weekday?

Answer (score -1):

Consider having a column

```
days_open TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT "0"
```

where the bits represent which days of the week it is open:

```
1 (bit 0): Sunday
2 (bit 1): Monday
4 (bit 2): Tuesday
...
64 (bit 6): Saturday
```

Note that you can use the following to check for Tuesday (bit 2); this can be treated as a boolean:

```
(days_open & (1 << 2))
```

The value 127 would mean open 7 days a week, etc.  Examples:

```
mysql> SELECT bin(127) AllDays, bin(65) Weekends, bin(62) Weekdays;
+---------+----------+----------+
| AllDays | Weekends | Weekdays |
+---------+----------+----------+
| 1111111 | 1000001  | 111110   |
+---------+----------+----------+
```